# .htaccess & mod_rewrite to rewrite to closest files

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

given a directory structure of:

```
/test/
/test/a
/test/a/b
/test/a/b/c
```

Each directory, in the above example, has an index file, index.php, in it. I have a single .htaccess in `/test/` ... I would like to avoid having a .htaccess in each directory.

I need to write a rewrite rule that will display the closest index.php to a URL that is entered into a system.

For example:

```
url /test/a/b/1234 should get rewritten to /test/a/b/index.php
url /test/a/b/c/1234 should get rewritten to /test/a/b/cindex.php
url /test/1234 should get rewritten to /test/index.php
```

I've tried several different .htaccess, but everything gets rewritten to `/test/index.php`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      RewriteEngine On

      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

      RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've also tried `RewriteRule . ./index.php [L]`

If i set a RewriteBase to be one of the sub directories it does rewrite to the index.php in that base. but then everything gets written to that base.

Thanks in advance.

Update:

The url length is unknown. Example:

```
url /test/a/b/1234/abcd/this/that/another should get rewritten to /test/a/b/index.php
```

Essentially, I need to know the directory from which .htaccess was matched in to use as the rewritebase for the rewriterule.

Comment: Capture the part before your `1234`, and use it in your replacement …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

## recursively search parent dir
# if index.php is not found then
# forward to the parent directory of current URI
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1$2/index.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)([^/]+)/[^/]+/?$ /$1$2/ [L]

# if current index.php is found in parent dir then load it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1index.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)[^/]+/?$ /$1index.php [L]
```

Comment: This fails with tests of `/a/b/1234/qwer/12321` which should rewrite to `/a/b/index.php`

Comment: Why should `/a/b/1234/qwer/12321` rewrite to `/a/b/index.php`? It will rewrite to `/a/b/1234/qwer/index.php` as that is the parent directory. Didn't you write `Each directory has an index file, index.php`

Comment: Each of the directories in the structure that I gave as an example. Anything else should rewrite to the closest index.php

Comment: Answer can be as good as question only. You started with `Each directory has an index file, index.php` and answer is based on that.

Comment: I started with "Giving this directory structure" 

I will update for clarification.

Comment: Excellent. It didn't occur to me to use a 2 step process of rewrite rules. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z]+)/([0-9]+)(.*)$ /test/$1/$2/$3/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^test/([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z]+)/([0-9]+)(.*)$ /test/$1/$2/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^test/([0-9]+)(.*)$ /test/index.php [L]
```

Comment: This solution also doesn't account for arbitrary directory depth.